# How to display state object elements in another component?

Tags: reactjs, react-context

i'm trying to use a table from MaterialUI and populate it with financial data (using promise API). I have three components:
**Gl.js**
**myTable**
**index.js**

I want to use the state object in the Gl.js component and populate the table in myTable.js but not sure how to. Please ask for more details if necessary, I must complete this project.

## **GL.js**

```
import React, { Component, createContext, Provider } from 'react';
    import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
    import axios from "axios";
    import CollapsibleTable from './myTable';

export const CTX = React.createContext();

class Gl extends React.Component {
    _isMounted = false;
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            applBs: []
        }
        
    }

    getData() {

        const axios = require("axios");

        axios({
            "method": "GET",
            "url": "https://fmpcloud.p.rapidapi.com/balance-sheet-statement/AAPL",
            "headers": {
                "content-type": "application/octet-stream",
                "x-rapidapi-host": "fmpcloud.p.rapidapi.com",
                "x-rapidapi-key": "4560d76562msh36c4de0a03c6e54p1bf4a2jsne2d882693304",
                "useQueryString": true
            }, "params": {
                "period": "annual",
                "apikey": "demo"
            }
        })
            .then(response => {
                if (this._isMounted) {
                    this.setState({ applBs: response.data[0] })
                }
            })
    
    
            .catch(error => {
                console.log(error)
            })

    }
    
    componentDidMount() {
        this._isMounted = true;
        this.getData();
    }

    componentWillUnamount() {
        this._isMounted = false;
    }


    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <CollapsibleTable callData={this.state.applBs} />

            <CTX.Provider value={ this.state.applBs }> 
                {this.props.children}
                </CTX.Provider>

                </div>
        )
    }
}




ReactDOM.render(<Gl />, document.getElementById("root"))

export default Gl
```

### **myTable.js**

```
import React, { Component, Consumer } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from "react-dom"
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import Box from '@material-ui/core/Box';
import Collapse from '@material-ui/core/Collapse';
import IconButton from '@material-ui/core/IconButton';
import Table from '@material-ui/core/Table';
import TableBody from '@material-ui/core/TableBody';
import TableCell from '@material-ui/core/TableCell';
import TableContainer from '@material-ui/core/TableContainer';
import TableHead from '@material-ui/core/TableHead';
import TableRow from '@material-ui/core/TableRow';
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';
import Paper from '@material-ui/core/Paper';
import KeyboardArrowDownIcon from '@material-ui/icons/KeyboardArrowDown';
import KeyboardArrowUpIcon from '@material-ui/icons/KeyboardArrowUp';
import CTX from "./GL.js"


const useRowStyles = makeStyles({
    root: {
        '& > *': {
            borderBottom: 'unset',
        },
    },
});

function createData(name, calories, fat, carbs, protein, price) {
    return {
        name,
        calories,
        fat,
        carbs,
        protein,
        price,
        history: [
            { lineItem: 'Pop', date: '2020-01-05', customerId: '11091700', amount: 3 },
            { lineItem: 'Pop', date: '2020-01-02', customerId: 'Anonymous', amount: 1 },
        ],
    };
}



function Row(props) {
    const { row } = props;
    const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);
    const classes = useRowStyles(); 

    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            <TableRow className={classes.root}>
                <TableCell>
                    <IconButton aria-label="expand row" size="small" onClick={() => setOpen(!open)}>
                        {open ? <KeyboardArrowUpIcon /> : <KeyboardArrowDownIcon />}
                    </IconButton>
                </TableCell>
                <TableCell component="th" scope="row">
                    {row.name} 
                </TableCell>
                <TableCell align="right">{row.calories}</TableCell>
                <TableCell align="right">{row.fat}</TableCell>
                <TableCell align="right">{row.carbs}</TableCell>
                <TableCell align="right">{row.protein}</TableCell>
            </TableRow>
            <TableRow>
                <TableCell style={{ paddingBottom: 0, paddingTop: 0 }} colSpan={6}>
                    <Collapse in={open} timeout="auto" unmountOnExit>
                        <Box margin={1}>
                            <Typography variant="h6" gutterBottom component="div">
                                History
              </Typography>
                            <Table size="small" aria-label="purchases">
                                <TableHead>
                                    <TableRow>
                                        <TableCell>
                                           Line Item
                                            </TableCell>
                                        <TableCell>
                                            Google
                                        </TableCell>
                                        <TableCell>
                                            Customer
                                            </TableCell>
                                        <TableCell align="right">
                                            Amount
                                            </TableCell>
                                        <TableCell align="right">
                                            Total price ($)
                                            </TableCell>
                                    </TableRow>
                                </TableHead>
                                <TableBody>
                                    {row.history.map((historyRow) => (
                                        <TableRow key={historyRow.date}>
                                            <TableCell component="th" scope="row">
                                                {historyRow.date}
                                            </TableCell>
                                            <TableCell>{historyRow.customerId}</TableCell>
                                            <TableCell align="right">{historyRow.amount}</TableCell>
                                            <TableCell align="right">
                                                {Math.round(historyRow.amount * row.price * 100) / 100}
                                            </TableCell>
                                        </TableRow>
                                    ))}
                                </TableBody>
                            </Table>
                        </Box>
                    </Collapse>
                </TableCell>
            </TableRow>
        </React.Fragment>
    );
}

Row.propTypes = {
    row: PropTypes.shape({
        calories: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
        carbs: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
        fat: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
        history: PropTypes.arrayOf(
            PropTypes.shape({
                amount: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
                customerId: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
                date: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
            }),
        ).isRequired,
        name: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
        price: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
        protein: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
    }).isRequired,
};

const rows = [
    createData('Frozen yoghurt', 159, 6.0, 24, 4.0, 3.99),
    createData('Ice cream sandwich', 237, 9.0, 37, 4.3, 4.99),
    createData('Eclair', 262, 16.0, 24, 6.0, 3.79),
    createData('Cupcake', 305, 3.7, 67, 4.3, 2.5),
    createData('Gingerbread', 356, 16.0, 49, 3.9, 1.5),
];

export default function CollapsibleTable() {
    return (
        <TableContainer component={Paper}>
            <Table aria-label="collapsible table">
                <TableHead>
                    <TableRow>
                        <TableCell />
                        <TableCell>
                            Apple.Inc
                        </TableCell>
                        <TableCell align="right">Calories</TableCell>
                        <TableCell align="right">Fat&nbsp;(g)</TableCell>
                        <TableCell align="right">Carbs&nbsp;(g)</TableCell>
                        <TableCell align="right">Protein&nbsp;(g)</TableCell>
                    </TableRow>
                </TableHead>
                <TableBody>
                    {rows.map((row) => (
                        <Row key={row.name} row={row} />
                    ))}
                </TableBody>
            </Table>
        </TableContainer>
    );
}
```

### **index.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import Gl from './GL';
import CollapsibleTable from './myTable';


ReactDOM.render(
    <React.StrictMode>
        <Gl >
            <CollapsibleTable />
            </Gl>

  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root'));
```

Comment: you're sending value in the name of `callData={this.state.applBs}` but in myTable.js i dont't see you're using `callData`

Comment: I tried using  {this.props.callData} but i get an error saying Cannot read property 'props' of undefined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok then this must be the issue be clear with class and functional component `this` keyword can be used only in class component!!

check this link for further reference [link](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html)

in your case have a console in

```
<TableContainer component={Paper}>
  {console.log('callData', props.callData)}
 <Table aria-label="collapsible table">
```

you will get the value of `callData` use that to display in table

Comment: I tried doing that but it said failed to compile 'callData' is not defined.

Comment: have you used `props.callData`

Comment: Yeah it says 'props' is not defined

Comment: `export default function(props)` add this functional components receives a default parameter "props " accept & upvote the answers if that helps

Comment: Not sure what to do honestly would I be able to contact you?

Comment: not a big issue just modify this line `export default function CollapsibleTable() ` to `export default function CollapsibleTable(props) ` it will work

Comment: glad that i could help ! keep coding